# TouchUpOutside is not working like it should

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I created a menue with some custom UIButtons. I only changed the drawRect function:

```
for button in buttons {
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showLabel), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(labelDelete), forControlEvents: .TouchUpOutside)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(labelDelete), forControlEvents: .TouchCancel)
        }
```

And I got three functions to handle the touchevents:

```
func labelDelete(sender: HexagonButton!) {
        label?.alpha = 0
        label?.hidden = true
    }
    func showLabel(sender: HexagonButton!) {
        label!.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2 - 150 + lastContentOffset, y: 5, width: 300, height: 30)
        label!.text = sender.labelName
        self.label?.hidden = false
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations:{
            self.label?.alpha = 1
        })

    }
    func buttonAction(sender: HexagonButton!) {
        label?.alpha = 0
        label?.hidden = true
        if sender.viewControllerName != "nil" {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(sender.viewControllerName)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }

    }
```

If I touch on one button the label appear like it should. But if I move my finger away from the button and leave the display it still call the .TouchUpInside function. It only works like it should if I move my finger a very long way off the button. What is the problem here?

Kindly Regards!

Comment: The touch up 'radius' goes outside the the button frame to account for fat fingers

Comment: Uff that must be very fat fingers! Can I change the radius?

Comment: I haven't touched UIButton in a long time,  when I get a chance i will dig up my old code and see what I did, if anything, to handle it